# Redirecting to homepage htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess

I have a strange issue where pages are redirecting to the homepage. Let me explain - my website is thedj.com.au

Now when I type in www.thedj.com.au/payments it redirects to thedj.com.au (even though it should be going to the page https://thedj.com.au/payments).

Any idea why this is and how to fix?

My htaccess file is below:

```
# BEGIN HTTPS Redirection Plugin
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home.htm$ https://thedj.com.au/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^photos.htm$ http://photos.thedj.com.au/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^contacts.htm$ https://thedj.com.au/contact-us/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^booking.htm$ https://thedj.com.au/book-dj/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^downloads.htm$ https://thedj.com.au/downloads/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^payonline.htm$ https://thedj.com.au/payments/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^price.htm$ https://thedj.com.au/pricing/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^questions.htm$ https://thedj.com.au/faq/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^links.htm$ https://thedj.com.au/links/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^thankyous/index.htm$ https://thedj.com.au/testimonials/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://thedj.com.au/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS Redirection Plugin

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mrdj\.net\.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mrdj\.net\.au$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/thedj\.com\.au\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mrdj\.com\.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mrdj\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/thedj\.com\.au\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thedjs\.com\.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thedjs\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/thedj\.com\.au\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^theperthweddingdjs\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.theperthweddingdjs\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/thedj\.com\.au\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thedjs\.net\.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.thedjs\.net\.au$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/thedj\.com\.au" [R=301,L]
```

Note:
I've tried commenting out the lines

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://thedj.com.au/ [L,R=301]
```

However this has not fixed the issue. I'm thinking this may perhaps be because the website is entirely https:// - but any more ideas would be much appreciated.

Best,
Kosta

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess shouldn't do any redirect here.
For testing, [this website](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) could be useful.

Is this configuration from your live site? Because https://thedj.com.au/payments works for me.
Browsers tend to cache permanent redirects quite aggressively. You need to clear the complete cache or use the private browsing mode to test a redirect again. (But you need to close ALL private browsing windows and then open a new one)

Comment: https://thedj.com.au/payments work however that is not the issue, the issue is www.thedj.com.au/payments does not redirect to https://thedj.com.au/payments as it should (it just redirects to the hompage). I have just tested this issue in Incognito mode just then and it is still doing it.